# Replaying voice messages does not work in the safari browser

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, safari

I am working on a NextJS/Typescript project where I have a chat feature that also implements voice messages. So far I managed to record the audio, make it replayable in the chatcomponent, send the url to my database and the file into an s3 bucket and I also get the data back correctly and can replay it in the chat history BUT not in the safari browser. I tried several packages including recordrtc, recorder-js, mp3-recorder, etc but nothing worked so far.
Does anyone have tipps or a tutorial on how to manage this? I appreciate every answer (:

Comment: Could you please give more details on how do you implement playing of audio and how you use mentioned packages. It would be enen better if you provide a sandbox, where you reproduce your problem.